# Max amount of peers connections on LND

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, p2p, peers

I'm trying to connect to a long list of peers. I'm running a LND(0.17.0) node.

My list has almost 1k peers and I can only connect to 6 of them. Is my node limiting the max connections? If so, is it possible to increase that max amount?

Comment: What operating system are you running? Many operating systems allow only 1024 open file discriptors concurrently by default.

Comment: @RenePickhardt Linux (Ubuntu)

Comment: [Answer] In principle there is no limit on the number of nodes to connect to. It seems that the firewall was blocking the traffic.